# call wizard (new api) inside product_id_change (old api ) , odoo v8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-8

i'm currently using odoo v8 , and ive been trying to call my wizard inside an old api function
here my wizard definition :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _


class cancel_reason (models.TransientModel):
_name = 'notify'
_description = "notify"
raison = fields.Text(default='')

@api.multi
def wizard_view(self, created_id):
    view = self.env.ref('product_end_life.notify')
    return {
        'name': 'Remplacement du produit',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': view.id,
        'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'notify',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': created_id,
    }
```

and here's the old api function , where i need to call my wizard 
i wont transform it to new api its gonna took much time :

```
def product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product,
                      qty=0, uom=False, qty_uos=0,
                      uos=False, name='', partner_id=False,
                      lang=False, update_tax=True,
                      date_order=False,
                      packaging=False, fiscal_position=False,
                      flag=False, context=None):

    res = super(sale_order_line, self).product_id_change(
        cr, uid, ids,
        pricelist, product,
        qty, uom, qty_uos,
        uos, name, partner_id,
        lang, update_tax,
        date_order, packaging,
        fiscal_position,
        flag, context=context)
```

> > here i need to call my wizard

```
return res
```

merci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research and reflection ,
we can't call wizard inside onchange methode 
not in odoo v8 
thnx